# Is there any way to extract distorted rectangle/square from the image?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, opencv

[image]

This is the image and I want to fill the edges of this rectangle or square so that I could crop it using contours. What I have done so far is that i used canny edge detector to find edges and then using bitwise_or I get this rectangle filled a little but not completely. What to do to fill this rectangle or is there any way to directly crop this?

```
image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/hp/Desktop/segmentation/test3.jpeg')

img3 = img2 = image.copy()
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

lower = np.array([155,25,0])
upper = np.array([179,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)

edges = cv2.Canny(mask, 1, 255, apertureSize=7)
result = cv2.bitwise_or(edges, mask)
```

Comment: Use the hough line transform to get the lines along the canny edges. Then find their intersections to get the 4 corners. Then draw a filled polygon or get the bounding box of the 4 corners and crop the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to extract the bounds of the rectangle white pixels in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold
- Do Canny edge detection
- Get Hough line segments and draw as white on black background
- Get the bounds of the white pixels
- Crop the input to the bounds

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('rect_lines.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold 
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(thresh, 100, 200)

# get hough line segments
threshold = 100
minLineLength = 50
maxLineGap = 20
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(thresh, 1, np.pi/360, threshold, minLineLength, maxLineGap)

# draw lines
linear = np.zeros_like(thresh)
for [line] in lines:
    #print(line)
    x1 = line[0]
    y1 = line[1]
    x2 = line[2]
    y2 = line[3]
    cv2.line(linear, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (255), 1)

# get bounds of white pixels
white = np.where(linear==255)
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = np.min(white[1]), np.min(white[0]), np.max(white[1]), np.max(white[0])
#print(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)

# draw bounding box on input
bounds = img.copy()
cv2.rectangle(bounds, (xmin,ymin), (xmax,ymax), (0,0,255))

# crop the image at the bounds
crop = img[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]

# save resulting masked image
cv2.imwrite('rect_lines_edges.png', edges)
cv2.imwrite('rect_lines_hough.png', linear)
cv2.imwrite('rect_lines_bounds.png', bounds)
cv2.imwrite('rect_lines_crop.png', crop)

# display result, though it won't show transparency
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("edges", edges)
cv2.imshow("lines", linear)
cv2.imshow("bounds", bounds)
cv2.imshow("crop", crop)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Canny edges:

[image]

Hough line segments:

[image]

Bounding box on input:

[image]

Cropped image:

[image]